# TabLayout и получение позиции

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Вопрос: почему при создании TabActivity мы сразу получаем позиции двух вкладок? Буквально создаются первые два фрагмента вне зависимости от количества вкладок (например, у меня их 3, но при создании активити порождаем только две вкладки)
Вопрос - ПОЧЕМУ?

У меня есть активити с табами, которую я создаю вот так:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_chart)
        val pageAdapter = TabsPageAdapter( supportFragmentManager, countItems)
        pager.adapter = pageAdapter
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager)
}
```

у меня есть адаптер, где фрагменты вкладок создаются вот так:

```
 override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> DailyProductivityFragment.newInstance(position)
            1 -> DailyProductivityFragment.newInstance(position)
            2 -> DailyProductivityFragment.newInstance(position)
            else -> throw Exception("Error in selection of fragment")
        }
    }
```

И у меня есть фрагмент, где экземпляр получаем вот так:

```
   companion object {
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

        fun newInstance(position: Int): DailyProductivityFragment {
            return DailyProductivityFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что мне в зависимости от полученного при создании фрагмента position нужно создавать разные данные в фрагменте. При создании активити я получаю position 0 и 1, но данные создаются ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ 1.
Уточню:

```
fun criterion(position: Int?) {
        when (position) {
            0 -> criterionChart = CriterionChart.TODAY
            1 -> criterionChart = CriterionChart.WEEK
            2 -> criterionChart = CriterionChart.ALL
        }
    }
```

Лог:

```
 E/MyLog: position 0
 E/MyLog: position 1
 E/MyLog: WEEK
 E/MyLog: WEEK
```

Меня интересует как исправить проблему, и самое главное, вообще ПОЧЕМУ создаются именно первых ДВА фрагмента. не три! не пять!
Гугление не дало ответа на этот вопрос
(я делала пустые проектики для примера, где не было ничего, кроме сгенерированных android studio для tabactivity классов, ситуация была аналогичной)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так работает `ViewPager`. Он по умолчанию загружает `n` фрагментов/View слева и справа от выбранного (0-ого фрагмента). Так и выходит, что загружается отображаемый фрагмент и следующий за ним.

При этом `n` можно назначить через метод `ViewPager#setOffscreenPageLimit(int count)`

Comment: поняла, спасибо большое